# Entity framework SaveChanges problems

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I have some issue with `DbContext.SaveChanges();`

I have table CAR which has FK to table ENGINE (Engine property has Attribute [Required]).
Also I implemented generic repository with update method.

```
 class Repo<T> where T : IArchivable{
      ...
      public void update(T row){
          row.Deleted = true; //Deleted is from interface IArchivable
          ctx.SaveChange();
      }
      .....
      public T Single(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition){
          return ctx.Set<T>().where<T>(condition);
      }
 }
```

in case :

```
      ....
      Repo<CAR> r = new Repo<CAR>();
      CAR car = r.Single(o => o.id == 1);
      r.update(car);
```

I will get error "Validation failed for one or more entities. ... " I checked it and the problem is that ENGINE property is require but for

```
      ....
      Repo<CAR> r = new Repo<CAR>();
      CAR car = r.Single(o => o.id == 1);
      car.Engine = car.Engine;
      r.update(car);
```

it will work.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Required` attribute from navigation property or turn off validation on data layer.

```
context.Configurations.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

The reason why it works in the second case is that you are accessing Engine property and EF will use lazy loading to load it from database but in the first case your code doesn't access the property and internal behavior in EF doesn't trigger it to avoid unexpected database round trips during save operation.